# Error initializing ctypes in pybuilder

Tags: python, openssl, ctypes, pyopenssl

A couple of days ago I cloned a git repository and tried to make a build out of that code with PyBuilder; however, I have not been able to do so.

Every time I run `pyb -X -E jenkins-zipfile-release` in Bash I get the following error: `BUILD FAILED - Error initializing ctypes`. The thing is, none of my colleagues have this problem, we don't know why.

The traceback tells me the problem is here: `.../pyenv/versions/2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscrypto/_openssl/_libcrypto_ctypes.py`

We thought the problem that my python was not correctly compiled with SSL. We even had a different SSL version. I replaced LibreSSL with OpenSSL, but the problem persists.

Another person told me that maybe the oscrypto libraries are conflicting (one from the environment and the other one from the project's lib directory) How can I check that?

I would deeply appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, I've been trying for two days now.

Comment: Please add the full traceback. Other useful info: *Python* version (*2.7.14* in *VEnv*), *PyBuilder* version, *pyOpenSSL* version, *OS* architecture.

Comment: @CristiFati I already looked into it and apparently there is an issue between the Oscrypto library and the High Sierra OS. I am able to make it work in other OS' except High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with regards to running oscrypto in a High Sierra. The issue was fixed and it will be a part of the next release.

More info: https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto/issues/22